# Why button Enable Condition after clicking radio button is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I try to enable delete button it doesn't work although I put logic for that.. In fact after putting the following the Delete button is always enable. Can't find the problem.
Here's the code:

Sports.js

```
// initiallising states
const [items1, setItems1] = useState({
pageCount: '',
field_names_state: [],
toggle: false,
elements: [],
data_form: [],
sports_id: '',
buttonDisable: "0",
}); 


const onRadioChange = (e) => {
items1.sports_id = e.target.value;
items1.buttonDisable="1";
alert(items1.buttonDisable);
};

// mapping our fetched data and send them to Table_Sports.js

const data1 = items1.elements.map((item) => (
<Table_Sports key={item.sports_id} item={item} action={onRadioChange} />
));

<button type='button' disabled={items1.buttonDisable=="1"} onClick={(e) => handleDelete(e)}>
    Delete
</button>
```

Table_Sports.js

```
  <td>
    <input
      type='radio'
      // defaultValue={props.item.sports_id}
      defaultValue={props.}
      name='sports_id'
      onClick={(e) => props.action(e)}
    />
  </td>

  <td>
    <input
      type='text'
      defaultValue={props.item.sports_name}
      name='sports_name'
      contentEditable='true'
    />
  </td>
```

Comment: You are not setting data properly inside  "onRadioChange" function. To update state parameter  value in react you need to write " setItems1({ ...items1, buttonDisable: "1" }); "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a value at the state, you should call setItems1, passing the new state object as a parameter instead of manipulate it's properties directly. If you change your onRadioChange function like this it should work:

```
const onRadioChange = (e) => {
    setItems1({
        ...items1,
        sports_id: e.target.value,
        buttonDisable: "1",
    });
};
```